# colocar uma lista inline materialize

Tags: css, materialize

Estou tentando colocar a lista de icones das redes sociais inline no meu footer, porém não estou obtendo sucesso. Essa alteração tem que ser feita direto no css do materialize? Segue código em anexo para ajudar. Obrigado

```html
<footer class="page-footer yellow darken-4">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col l6 s12">
        <h5 class="white-text">Footer Content</h5>
        <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">You can use rows and columns here to organize your footer content.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col l4 offset-l2 s12">
        <h5 class="white-text">Links</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!"><i class="fa fa-vimeo fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer-copyright">
    <div class="container">
      © 2014 Copyright Text
      <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4 right" href="#!">More Links</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: No CSS dos itens da lista `display: inline;` ou `display: inline-block;`. Nunca se deve alterar os arquivos do framework/template, crie um para o seu CSS custumizado e sobrescreva o anterior

Answer (score 1):

No seu `footer` coloque `display: inline`.

```
footer ul li{
  display: inline;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hv7L0a3k/2/)

Comment: Rapaz, eu já ia colocar isso, mas você foi mais rápido no gatilho! kkk

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma classe `inline` assim:

```
.inline li{
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Depois, basta chamar esse classe em sua `<ul>`, como nesse [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hv7L0a3k/)

Comment: Obrigado deu tudo certo!!